# Use an arraylist in file input output java

Tags: java, arraylist, file-io, fileinputstream

So, here is the question. I want to create a file using java GUI, this is something like the user can create an account or login in my GUI, and then their account becoming file.txt in mine. But, I have a problem here. When I create an account in my GUI, it works well, and the file is created. But, when I tried to create an account again, an account that have been created before is gone. So, I guess I need to use arraylist in this case, and I use it, but it still doesn't work. Here is the code :

```
String filename="D:/settings.txt";

public void getIdentity() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    File file = new File(filename);
    ArrayList identity = new ArrayList();

    String fullname = txt_fullname.getText();
    String username = txt_username.getText();
    String password = pass_password.getText();

    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename);
        Writer output = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        identity.add(fullname + "-" + username + "-" + password);

        for (int i = 0; i <identity.size(); i++)
        {
         output.write(identity.get(i).toString() + "\n");
        }
        output.close();
    }


    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot create a file");
    }

}
```

And this is the action :

```
try {

        if(txt_username.getText() != null && pass_password.getText() != null
           && txt_fullname.getText() != null)
        {
        getIdentity(); 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congratulations, you've created a file");
        this.setVisible(false);
        Login login = new Login();
        login.setVisible(true);
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill in your identity");
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {

    }
```

Comment: If this answer is right for you, please mark answer as "accepted".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename);`

So your file is overridden over and over every time your function is called.

So you have two options:

1. Store one credential to each setting file name. (you can distinguish the file by appending username to your settings file, for example)
2. Store all credential to `settings` file. But you have to open your file in `append` mode

   ```
       FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename, true); // true flag indicate appending mode
   ```

   And you have to change your reading side too, since your settings file now store all credential.